# Ruby on Rails Selenium Load Test

Tags: ruby, selenium, ruby-on-rails-3, jmeter, load-testing

I've written few Selenium Automated tests in Ruby which work fine and would love to know if there's a way to use them for Load Testing. Few last days I'm looking for a solution to do so with JMeter. Could any of you tip me to right direction.

Update after Dmitri T anwser:
I guess I should've mentioned it before, there are few problems that make it hard for me to find a solution on Jmeter:

1. My Selenium Automated tests are run from .bat file where a total of 42 .rb files are called each after another where each file starts and ends by user login/logout, and browser closing.
2. Global variables are being used in each test, where they get changed depending on date and number of times the tests were run today.

I've tried WebDriver Sampler solution, but as Dmitri metioned it's not a viable option since I would need enourmous amounts of resource to run multiple browser instances.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to run Ruby code in JMeter given you have [JRuby library](https://www.jruby.org/) in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

However using real browsers for performance testing is not the best idea because they're **very** resource intensive. For example [Firefox 102 requires 1 CPU and 2 GB of RAM](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/102.0/system-requirements/) per browser instance so on 16-core and system with 16GB of RAM you will be only able to simulate 15 virtual users. And with JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler you will be able to mimic hundreds if not thousands users on this hardware.

So instead of trying to run existing Ruby tests using JMeter in multithreaded manner I would rather recommend converting them into "vanilla" JMeter tests. For example you can

1. Start [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733979-Recording-a-user-session-with-the-proxyhttps://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733979-Recording-a-user-session-with-the-proxy)
2. Configure your Ruby tests to [use JMeter as the proxy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/shared/#proxy)
3. Run your Ruby tests
4. JMeter will capture the traffic and generate appropriate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers for it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
By the looks of it, your solution should work well with a single test. 
Would it work fine with multiple .rb tests run consecutively?
I did not explain my situation fully.
I'll update my main question after this. To make a short comment here: there are multiple .rb tests, they're run one after another thus close browser each time, there are also variables that are beeing changed during the Automated Test.
Wouldn't closing the browser at test's end stop the Jmeter recording?
Wouldn't Jmeter recording just keep on testing with the same value?

Comment: JMeter will stop recording when **you** decide to stop recording and it will capture each and every request which is coming through its proxy. Most probably you will need to perform some [correlation of the dynamic parameters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) or use online recording solutions like [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder) which automatically detect and handle dynamic values.

Comment: Much obliged, will try it out.